# Outlook ".EML" file Directory on MAC?

Tags: php, macos, outlook

I am writing a script in PHP for scanning emails ".eml" files for bad email addresses, So i am unable to locate the file directory of outlook where it saves ".eml" files on MAC OS.

I have Checked this directory: user/rotate/library/group containers/UBF8T346G9.office/outlook/outlook 15 profiles/Main Profile/Data/Messages/

But its not there, Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to look for something like:

```
/Users/me/Library/Group Containers/123THEID.Office/Outlook/Outlook 15 Profiles/Main Profile/Data/Messages/
```

You will find a lot of folders with numerical names, from 0 to 255. There doesn't seem to be any alphabetical or chronological logic to it, so it's all a dumb storage with the mapping done in some other folder or DB. A good candidate is `…/Main Profile/Data/Outlook.sqlite`.